# How do I write to a file from new Linux system call in a loop from a Kthread

Tags: c, linux, linux-kernel, kernel, ubuntu-16.04

I am using a kthread as a worker to write to a file. I want the kthread to keep writing once the initial system call has terminated. The thread is writing data from a buffer. I open the file and the kthread like this:

```
f = filp_open(file, O_RDWR | O_APPEND, 0);
if (!f)
{
    return -1;
}
running_thread = kthread_run(write_to_disk_thread, (void*)&thread_args, "write_to_disk");
```

I then run this code in a loop on the thread. text_to_append is the next char* to be written from the buffer. It is created by kmalloc() and then the data is coppied into it on each loop. popped_length is its length.

```
loff_t pos = f->f_pos;
__kernel_write(f, text_to_append, popped_length, &pos);
pos += popped_length;
set_fs(KERNEL_DS);
__fput_sync(f);
f->f_pos = pos;
vfs_fsync_range(f, pos-popped_length, pos, 1);
set_fs(old_fs);`
```

When I run my code I get a null pointer bug but only on the second iteration of the loop.

[image: screenshot of error]

Comment: AFAIK, `__kernel_write` would update `pos` with the new position. I don't see a point in this line `pos += popped_length;`.

Comment: If I try opening the file from within the kthread then it fails to open the file. I get a null pointer error in strlen() from getname_kernel from filp_open()